# Winter 14 Apex Test Execution - tests never finish

Tags: developer-console, winter14

Winter 14 - sandbox cs9

I have 50+ test classes; I do Apex Test Execution | Select tests | select all.

- Disable parallel testing = true
- Store only aggregated test coverage = true

I select all tests. Within a few minutes, about 40 of the test classes finish execution; 10 or so never finish. Even after one hour of waiting. This never used to happen as I have done this sequence repeatedly over the last few months/years. This makes it hard to run regression tests.

Things I tried:

1. Taking one of the 'never finishing' classes, aborting it, and running it solo. RESULT: It never finishes execution
2. Recompiling one of the 'never finishing' classes and running it solo. RESULT: It never finishes execution
3. Using Eclipse Force.com IDE and Apex Run Tests on one of the manually-aborted, 'never finishing' test classes - Eclipse comes back with 'Unable to run tests on 'Foo.cls': Running test: Foo, time spent on that test 1974ms, total time spent running tests 18715ms. Error: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 170253947-20552(2105728326)
4. Refreshed fullcopy sandbox (cs11) from PROD 30 minutes ago. Ran tests on one of the classes that 'never finished' in cs9 - same error in CS11. Note that test of said class in PROD passes

Analysis - based on #4, it would appear something was introduced into at least cs9 and cs11 sandboxes that prevent certain test classes from executing. Given that cs11 is a fullcopy of PROD and class Foo runs fine in PROD but not in cs11 (fullcopy), the problem must be related to sandboxes

So, I contacted support. Waiting for assistance.

Comment: OK, support states that this is a known issue relating to a recent patch involving code coverage and that SFDC India is working on it as I type. Error code is 2105728326. They didn't identify the specific patch but is related to one of these I would surmise: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_index?tag=Winter%2014

Comment: Looks like SFDC may have backed out the fix to: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T0FeAAK as my tests now execute but with the Red X and error 'tests cannot be run for class <id>' - however, double clicking the line shows that all testmethods passed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem resolved by SFDC by applying patch or rolling back patch in CS9 (hard to tell what they did). All tests now execute to completion. None show 'Red X could not run tests on class ' Should someone still be experiencing this, they can reference SFDC Support Case 09880471 and apparently related case 09881682